# Dropdown position Issue

Tags: html, css, sass, web

I'm working on navbar dropdown menu and him having some trouble trying to position the dropdown menu with a width 100% but when every I put width to 100% it expands to right but not the left side.

Here the link to a preview of my project working on. Hope someone by can help with the small quick problem having.

Preview Link --> https://brandonpowell.github.io/alegacyleftbehind/

[This is what trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5haOW.png)

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar-default primary-nav navbar-fixed-top nav-down">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="top-navbar">
<div class="media-icons">
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#"><div class="donate-button">
<p>Donate</p>
</div></a>

<div class="bottom-navbar">
<div class="logo">Logo Here</div>
<div class="nav-menu"><img src="icons/menu.svg"></div>
<ul class="navbar">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Founder's Message</a></li>
<li><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About Us</a>
<ul class="nav-content">
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">dropdown item 6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Join Our Team</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News & Events</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Campus Clubs</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
body, html {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

nav .top-navbar {
  background-color: #212121;
  position: absolute;
  height: 67px;
  width: 100%; }

.donate-button {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 1; }
  .donate-button p {
    font-style: Montserrat, sans-serif;
    background-color: #961de7;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding: 21.4px 35px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white; }

.bottom-navbar {
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); }

.nav-menu {
  display: none; }

.navbar {
  display: table; }
  .navbar a:hover {
    color: pink; }
  .navbar li {
    display: table-cell;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase; }
    .navbar li a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #212121; }

.nav-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 13.3em;
  z-index: -1;
  padding: 1.3em 0 !important;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #a656dc; }
  .nav-content a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none; }

.logo {
  background-color: #961de7;
  color: white;
  font-size: 16pt;
  float: left;
  padding: 39px 6%; }
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add a value for 'left' to the nav-content div like this:

```
   .nav-content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 13.3em;
        z-index: -1;
        padding: 1.3em 0 !important;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #a656dc;
        left: 0; /*add this*/
    }
```

and to center the menu add margin:auto to the ul element like this:

```
    .nav-content ul {
        margin:auto;
    }
```